# In React, How do I create a dictionary to change multiple values based on a single prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, components

I have the following code. I know their are multiple ways of doing this and I could make it using conditional return but I would like to know if theres a more efficient way of doing it.

This is my component example

```
export default function APIListThingy({
  title = "List Component",
  type = "dog",
}: {
  title?: string;
  type: "dog" | "cat" | "bunny";
}) {
```

I have "Dog" | "Cat" | "Bunny" to each have a specific set of visual changes (background color, text color), and functional from the API its calling to.

What would be the best way to do this?

Edit:

I have tried the following and works fine.

```
const variables = {
    dog: {
      bg: "#333",
      icon: "dog-outline",
    },
    cat : {
      bg: "#444",
      icon: "cat-outline",
    },
    bunny : {
      bg: "#555",
      icon: "bunny-outline",
    },
  };
```

and I just call it with

```
variables[type]
```

Comment: Don't want to be a snob, sorry for that :D but it would be better to try your ideas first and present them here, might be there is no more efficient way or your would be good enough. I bet you must use a switch case or lookup dict to achieve different set of props based on your type

Comment: I didn't use anything actually. I had the switch case in mind, but just felt it would be too much replication considering it's a big component, until the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it would be simplier to create some generic component let's say Animal, that would accept those style values and apply them. Then make your APIListThingy to simply pass props to it like this:

`<Animal {...variables[type]} />`

So you were basically already doing the right thing.

Your `variables` object/dictionary works as, so called, "lookup" mapping and imho is a better and more readable alternative to a `switch-case`